# filtrar listas vacias

Tags: r

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
da1<-data.frame(col1=c(3),col2=c("pepe"))
da2<-data.frame(col1=c(5),col2=c("pepe"))
da3<-data.frame()
da4<-data.frame(col1=c(3),col2=c("pepe"))
da5<-data.frame()
da6<-data.frame(col1=c(5),col2=c("pepe"))

dat<-list()
dat[["da1"]]<-da1
dat[["da2"]]<-da2
dat[["da3"]]<-da3
dat[["da4"]]<-da4
dat[["da5"]]<-da5
dat[["da6"]]<-da6
```

¿Se le puede aplicar algo a `dat` para que detecte que da3 y da5 están vacías y las elimine?
De manera que la lista dat solo contendría a `da1,da2,da4,da6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat[lapply(dat,length)>0]
```

Lo que estamos haciendo:

- Aplicamos `length` a cada elemento de `dat`
- Finalmente seleccionamos de `dat` solo aquellos elementos cuya longitud sea mayor a 0.